# Configuring WSGI (flask factory) with PythonAnywhere

Tags: python, flask, wsgi, pythonanywhere

I'm having issues with deploying a Flask Application with WSGI and PythonAnywhere. I assume I have done something wrong but I wasn't able to find exactly what I did do wrong.

Here's my WSGI config file

```
import sys
# add your project directory to the sys.path
project_home = u'/home/{redacted}/src'
if project_home not in sys.path:
    sys.path = [project_home] + sys.path
from start import run as application
```

Here's start.py

```
from bin import app
run = app.register().run()
```

Although if I try it this way it still does not work

```
from bin import app
run = app.register()
```

And here's what I'm doing in bin/main.py

```
class Application():
    # Some required code redacted, although not necessary for this example
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    def register(self):
        """ Starts Flask App """
        try:
            self.configure_app()
            self.register_blueprints()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error configuring Application: {e}")
        return self.app
app = Application()
```

Just in case you're interested, here's how it's imported through bin/__ init __.py

```
from .main import app
```

I do understand that the method in which I am doing this is over complicating it a little bit, and that I could get it working with a more normal method. Although I want it done this way and I'm fairly sure it can work this way, because the example I've shown 100% works on my machine.

Help is very appreciated. I am 100% aware I am doing something wrong here I just need help figuring out what it is.

Comment: Look in your error and server logs for tracebacks that you can use to start debugging.